# Add signature to email

Tags: excel, vba

I'm trying to utilize my default signature when I send an automated email.

My code pastes the location of the signature rather than the signature itself.

```vb
Sub CreateEmailForGTB()
        
    Dim wb As Workbook
       
    Set wb = Workbooks.Add
    ThisWorkbook.Sheets("BBC").Copy After:=wb.Sheets(1)
       
    'save the new workbook in a dummy folder
    wb.SaveAs "location.xlsx"
         
    'close the workbook
    ActiveWorkbook.Close
         
    'open email
    Dim OutApp As Object
    Dim OutMail As Object
    Dim newDate: newDate = Format(DateAdd("M", -1, Now), "MMMM")
    Dim sigstring As String
    
    Set OutApp = CreateObject("Outlook.Application")
    Set OutMail = OutApp.CreateItem(0)
    
    sigstring = Environ("appdata") & _
                "\Microsoft\Signatures\zbc.htm"
    
    'fill out email
    With OutMail
        .To = "abc@domain.com;"
        .CC = "xyz@domain.com;"
        .BCC = ""
        .Subject = "VCR - CVs for BBC " & "- " & newDate & " month end."
        .Body = "Hi all," & vbNewLine & vbNewLine & _
                 "Please fill out the attached file for " & newDate & " month end." & vbNewLine & vbNewLine & _
                 "Looking forward to your response." & vbNewLine & vbNewLine & _
                 "Many thanks." & vbNewLine & vbNewLine & _
                 sigstring
```

Comment: Can you post the rest of your `With OutMail` code?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's another way to grab to display the signature in a email message, that in easier to use in my opinion. It does require that you have set up your signature to display on new messages by default.

See the routine I have set up below for how to implement.

```
Sub SendMail(strTo As String, strSubject As String, strBody As String, strAttachments As String, Optional strCC As String, Optional strFolder As String, Optional blSend As Boolean)

'*******************************************************************
'**    Sub:         SendMail
'**    Purpose:     Prepares email to be sent
'**    Notes:       Requires declaration of Outlook.Application outside of sub-routine
'**                 Passes file name and folder for attachments separately
'**                 strAttachments is a "|" separated list of attachment paths
'*******************************************************************

'first check if outlook is running and if not open it
Dim olApp As Outlook.Application

On Error Resume Next
Set olApp = GetObject(, "Outlook.Application")
On Error GoTo 0
If olApp Is Nothing Then Set olApp = New Outlook.Application

Dim olNS As Outlook.Namespace
Dim oMail As Outlook.MailItem

'login to outlook
Set olNS = olApp.GetNamespace("MAPI")
olNS.Logon

'create mail item
Set oMail = olApp.CreateItem(olMailItem)

'display mail to get signature
With oMail
    .display
End With

Dim strSig As String
strSig = oMail.HTMLBody

'build mail and send
With oMail

    .To = strTo
    .CC = strCC
    .Subject = strSubject
    .HTMLBody = strBody & strSig

    Dim strAttach() As String, x As Integer
    strAttach() = Split(strAttachments, "|")

    For x = LBound(strAttach()) To UBound(strAttach())
        If FileExists(strFolder & strAttach(x)) Then .Attachments.Add strFolder & strAttach(x)
    Next

    .display
    If blSend Then .send

End With

Set olNS = Nothing
Set oMail = Nothing

End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to actually get the text from the file as opposed to just setting the filepath as a string like you are now. I'd suggest something like this:

```
Function GetText(sFile As String) As String

   Dim nSourceFile As Integer, sText As String

   ''Close any open text files
   Close

   ''Get the number of the next free text file
   nSourceFile = FreeFile

   ''Write the entire file to sText
   Open sFile For Input As #nSourceFile
   sText = Input$(LOF(1), 1)
   Close

   GetText = sText

End Function
```

Source: http://www.exceluser.com/excel_help/questions/vba_textcols.htm

You can then simply use this in your code:

```
sigstring = GetText(Environ("appdata") & "\Microsoft\Signatures\zbc.htm")
```

Answer (score 0):

Your variable `sigstring` literally is just the name of the file - you never read the file contents.
To read the contents try this (and don't forget to declare a variable (`text` and `line` in my example) to hold the file contents).

```
sigstring = Environ("appdata") & "\Microsoft\Signatures\zbc.htm"
Open sigstring For Input As #1
Do Until EOF(1)
    Line Input #1, line
    text = text & line
Loop
Close #1
```

Answer (score 0):

You can add your default signature by  entering the items .Display right after your With statements and adding .body on the body message. see below code

With OutMail

```
.Display
.To = "abc@domain.com;"
     .CC = "xyz@domain.com;"
    .BCC = ""
    .Subject = "VCR - CVs for BBC " & "- " & newDate & " month end."
    .Body = "Hi all," & vbNewLine & vbNewLine & _
             "Please fill out the attached file for " & newDate & " month end." & vbNewLine & vbNewLine &  .body
             "Looking forward to your response." & vbNewLine & vbNewLine & _
             "Many thanks." & vbNewLine & vbNewLine
```